# How to call a function in a Blazor component from a Razor page

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I'm creating a [MarkdownEditor](https://github.com/erossini/BlazorMarkdownEditor/tree/Using-EasyMDE) component for Blazor based on [EasyMDE](https://easy-markdown-editor.tk/). The project on GitHub is working apart from the file upload because I can't find a way to run a function in the component from the page.

I explain with same code because I don't know how to explain better. This is the basic code for the `MarkdownEditor` in a Razor page. There are some events that I map such as `ImageUploadChanged`

```
<MarkdownEditor Value="@markdownValue" ValueChanged="@OnMarkdownValueChanged"
                ImageUploadEndpoint="https://localhost:7013/api/Image"
                ImageUploadChanged="@OnImageUploadChanged"
                ImageUploadStarted="@OnImageUploadStarted"
                ImageUploadProgressed="@OnImageUploadProgressed"
                ImageUploadEnded="@OnImageUploadEnded" />

async Task OnImageUploadChanged(FileChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // e contains the image to upload via API
    // at the end I want to execute ImageUploadEnded
}
```

In the MarkdownEditor, the user can upload images. When an image is dropped on the editor, the event `ImageUploadChanged` is fired from the component.

The UI has to upload the file somewhere via API. I like to show to the user the progression of the upload. So, I have to call a function in the `MarkdownEditor` to update the user about the status of a specific file.

Similarly, when the upload is completed, I have to notify the `MarkdownEditor` the URL of the image. So, it adds the classic string in the text. For that, I have to execute a call to the JavaScript and pass some parameters that only the component knows such as the `ElementId`.

If I add a `@ref="@ElementRef"` I don't have access to the public function from the component. Also, I don't want to invoke a JavaScript from the component because I think it is not very elegant.

Basically, I want to call the function `notifyImageUploadSuccess` in the `markdownEditor.js` ([here the code](https://github.com/erossini/BlazorMarkdownEditor/blob/ca26a99fc841fea9fe54b51f8f5bc7ebe3b8ee11/PSC.Blazor.Components.MarkdownEditor/wwwroot/js/markdownEditor.js#L144))

```
function notifyImageUploadSuccess(elementId, imageUrl) {
    const instance = _instances[elementId];

    if (instance) {
        return instance.imageUploadNotifier.onSuccess(imageUrl);
    }
}
```

The UI knows only the `imageUrl` and for this reason I have to pass the `imageUrl` to the component and then the component has to call the JavaScript function.

I can't find a way. Maybe it is very simple.

Comment: Can you share the code where you use JSInterop?

Comment: You have the JSInterop [here](https://github.com/erossini/BlazorMarkdownEditor/blob/Using-EasyMDE/PSC.Blazor.Components.MarkdownEditor/JSMarkdownInterop.cs) and also the full project with same example in the [repo](https://github.com/erossini/BlazorMarkdownEditor) in the branch called `Using-EasyMDE`

Comment: Finally, I found a solution. I have created a Markdown Editor component for Blazor that you can find on GitHub https://github.com/erossini/BlazorMarkdownEditor

Answer (score 0):

In Upload.razor update [MarkdownEditor] like this line:

> <MarkdownEditor @ref="markdownEditor" AutoSaveEnabled="true"
> AutoSaveId="UploadPage"
> Value="@markdownValue" ValueChanged="@OnMarkdownValueChanged"
> ValueHTMLChanged="@OnMarkdownValueHTMLChanged"
> ImageUploadEndpoint="https://localhost:7013/api/files"
> ImageUploadChanged="@OnImageUploadChanged"
> ImageUploadStarted="@OnImageUploadStarted"
> ImageUploadProgressed="@OnImageUploadProgressed"
> ImageUploadEnded="@OnImageUploadEnded"
> UploadImage="true" />

In same page code add:

> ```
> MarkdownEditor markdownEditor { get; set; }
> ```

In same page code update this methode like this code:

> ```
> async Task OnImageUploadChanged(FileChangedEventArgs e)
> {
>     if (e.Files.Length > 0)
>         await markdownEditor.NotifyImageUpload(e.Files[0]);
>     this.StateHasChanged();
> }
> ```